# Vim Ctags how to auto complete function arguments?

Tags: c++, function, vim, autocomplete, ctags

I'm wondering if it's possible or not to auto complete function arguments from tags generated by exuberant ctags? I noticed that when I generate a tag, I see the function argument WITH the function, so it would be logical to assume that it's possible to complete the arguments.

I'm familiar that there are alternatives such as clang_complete and youcompleteme, which uses the clang compiler, but that's an added dependency. I'm already using Tagbar + EasyTags, etc, so why not just use tags if it's already there, than to bloat up vim.

Comment: I tried some plugins that use ctags and completes function arguments (don't remember exact names though), but they are all works bad on rather large projects: similar function names are pretty common case (say, member functions of different classes).I also used omnicppcomplete for about a year, on large projects it works ugly too. I really suggest you to try plugins that use clang, it works great: completion by real compiler, not ugly method by ctags. I feel happy with completion by clang.

Comment: You might be better off by switching from context-less ctags to context-aware clang-complete or YCM. That being said, I don't think they complete the function arguments. YCM is really *cool*, being able to type just a couple of letters from the word (not necessarily the prefix) and have it complete the actual thing I want is nice. BTW, why function arguments? How often you want to use exactly the same names as the signature has?

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're trying to achieve. What do you mean by "complete function arguments"? You can pass anything at all to a function: a literal string, a variable name, the result of another function call, a literal hex number, etc. Any of these can be completed as you type with another invocation of the completion function. Or, do you just want to see a guide as to what arguments a function takes?

Comment: What do you mean? I meant function arguments as in "int Add (int a, int b)" so when I try to complete a function, it would show Add (int a, int b), instead of just Add. Also, using ctags is still very good, I can use Tagbar to show me my functions in a class, etc, which makes viewing source code pretty easy. And I use cscope + ctags in conjunction, so if I want a definition or something, I can easily get it. Anyways, right now I'm using YCM, Ctags, Cscope and Tagbar for my C/C++ development tools.

Comment: @Ben I want to see a guide to what arguments a function takes, basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really "completion" of the function arguments, but from the comments on your question you said you want a guide to what arguments a function takes after doing tag completion.

If your completion method supports it, you can see such a guide with `:set completeopt+=preview`.

The C filetype plugin distributed with Vim sets the `'omnifunc'` option to `ccomplete#Complete` which supports this option, using the tag signature. I believe it also works for C++. You may need a similar completion function for other languages.

To use it, do "omni" type completion after setting the option, with `<C-X><C-O>` in insert mode.